# Subclassing button with a textField property to use same selector method for multiple textFields in Swift - alternative approach?

Tags: ios, swift, selector

EDIT 1: All of my code works, this is just to know of other alternatives / better approach to use the same selector method in such a scenario.

EDIT 2: Sequence of events- User taps on `textField` > `datePicker` appears on the screen (on the tap of `textField`) > User selects a date and presses `done` button (`doneBarButton` in the toolbar of `datePicker`) > selected date is displayed in the `textField`

I'm trying to use the same selector method `doneBarButtonClicked` of `doneBarButton` in the `toolBar` of a `datePicker` for two textFields to get date displayed in them. I've done this by having a subclass of `UIBarButton`, having `textField` as a property. I want to know if this is a good approach, also the possible alternatives of this.
I've two textFields, let's say:

```
    textField1: UITextField!
    textField2: UITextField!
```

The `doneBarButton` is initialized using `doneBarBtn` class, which is subclassed from `UIBarButton` having `textField` as a property.

```
 class doneBarBtn: UIBarButtonItem {
        var textField: UITextField?
}
```

Now, when the user taps a textField, the `datePicker` is shown. I've created the `datePicker` (with a `toolbar` having the `doneBarButton` in the `viewDidLoad` and calling it by inspecting using the delegate function of the `UITextField`, `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`. Let's say, for `textField1` having the selector in the `addTarget` method as `#selector(ViewController.showDatePickerHelper)`. The helper function is as-

```
    func showDatePickerHelper(){
    if(textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField1)){showDatePicker(textField: textField1)}
}
```

And the code for `showDatePicker` having textField as an argument and the selector `doneBarButtonClicked` of `doneBarButton` is as:

```
   func showDatePicker(textField : UITextField){

    // DatePicker access
    textField.inputView = self.datePicker
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    //doneBarButton selector and textField
    doneBarButton.textField = textField
    doneBarButton.action = #selector(doneBarButtonClicked)
}

func doneBarButtonClicked() {
    let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.dateStyle = .medium
    dateFormatter1.timeStyle = .none

    doneBarButton.textField?.text = dateFormatter1.string(from: datePicker.date)
    doneBarButton.textField?.resignFirstResponder()    
   }
```

Since, selector methods/functions are treated differently from regular methods, I reckoned we cannot pass the textField as an argument to the `doneBarButtonClicked`, but I'd like to know the alternatives in such a scenario. I'm using XCode 8.2.1 and Use Legacy Swift Language Version is set to NO in my build settings.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to produce? This seems kind of convoluted.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ I want to know a different approach to pass an argument to a selector method. I mean in this case, I couldn't pass textField as an argument to my selector method doneBarButtonClicked

Comment: What UX functionality? Usually when you're trying to do funky things like this there's a better/simpler design that solves your problem.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Like in this case, on the tap of a textField, a datePicker is shown, which has a done button, which has a selector method when clicked. I want to use the same selector method on done button clicked for both the textFields, I'm a little new to Swift, so spent some time in reaching this point, would be happy if you can add some knowledge to my understanding till yet.

Comment: Why are you using a TextField rather than a Button?

Comment: Requirement of the design

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159415/discussion-between-thirteenth-and-peejweej).

Comment: If it's not functioning as a text field, (which it probably can't if it's tapped) I would recommend putting a clear button over the whole area.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ you mean, then use the label property of that clear button to display the date when the done button is clicked? But then also, I'd require sending button as an argument to the doneBarButtonClicked method of the doneBarButton, which is on the datePicker. How would that solve the problem?

Comment: I'm saying rather than using textFieldShouldBeginEditing, (which has a different intended purpose), overlay a button over the text fields. Regardless, if you're intending to replicate this kind of functionality with multiple textfields, I would recommend encapsulating it into it's own View or ViewController class rather than trying to manage each one individually.

Comment: Good point on the delegate part. I was actually thinking to make the view separate for all of these elements. Just to be sure, I'm on the same page could you please link me to some example?